# Disable click outside modal close React Js coreui modal-outside click the popup don't close modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, core-ui

```
     const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
return (
  
     setVisible(!visible)}>Launch static backdrop modal
     setVisible(false)}>
      
        Modal title
      
      
        I will not close if you click outside me. Don't even try to press escape key.
      
      
         setVisible(false)}>
          Close
        
        Save changes
      
    
  
)
```

Core Ui react modal outside click the popup doesn't close modal setup not working, any option there, I'm also tried backdrop{true/false}

Comment: you don't want to close modal when click outside, right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: you can check here in their documentation, check static backdrop example https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/modal/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/modal/#static-backdrop) static Modal Component instead of dynamic one.

> If you set a backdrop to static, your React modal component will behave as though the backdrop is static, meaning it will not close when clicking outside it. Click the button below to try it.

Edit: If you read this table at the end of [this doc](https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/modal/),[image: table] you will notice that you can use type 'static' to make modal doesn't close on outside click.

This code below will be an example on how to use:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
return (
  <>
    <CButton onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>Launch static backdrop modal</CButton>
    <CModal visible={visible} onClose={() => setVisible(false)} backdrop={'static'}>  // this will make modal deosn't exit on outside click
      <CModalHeader>
        <CModalTitle>Modal title</CModalTitle>
      </CModalHeader>
      <CModalBody>
        I will not close if you click outside me. Don't even try to press escape key.
      </CModalBody>
      <CModalFooter>
        <CButton color="secondary" onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>
          Close
        </CButton>
        <CButton color="primary">Save changes</CButton>
      </CModalFooter>
    </CModal>
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a solution using jquery.

```
import $ from 'jquery';

useEffect( () => {
  $(document).on('click', '.modal.loading', () => setShowModal(0));  // <- add this
}, []);

    <CModal className="modal" visible={showModal == 3} >
      <CModalBody className="text-center">
        <CSpinner color="light"/>
      </CModalBody>
    </CModal>
```